# Access current user in custom django widget

Tags: python, django

I have a custom widget used to replace the dropdown for the `ForeignKey` field with a list of images with radiobuttons. In my `render` method I need to access the current user (the user who is currently logged in), like I would in a normal view with using `request.user`.

I have read a lot of solutions to do this with `Forms`, that you should pop the user object from `**kwargs` in your `__init__` method.

However widgets doesn't have `**kwargs` in their `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    if attrs is not None:
        self.attrs = attrs.copy()
    else:
        self.attrs = {}
```

**How do I access the current user within a `Widget` sub-class?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by reading through the Django source: Pass the user object when setting the `formfield_overrides` in the custom admin.

I have 2 models: `News` and `Image`. `Image` contains a name field and an `ImageField`. The `News` model contains a `ForeignKey` which points to image:

```
class News(models.Model):
    ... bunch of news related fields
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
```

Then in my `admin.py` I have a custom admin class for news:

```
class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = News
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        self.formfield_overrides = {
            models.ForeignKey : {'widget' : SelectForeign(user = request.user)}
        }

        return super(NewsAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Then in my `widget.py` I have a custom widget class:

```
class SelectForeign(widgets.Widget):
    current_user = None

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=(), user = None):
        self.current_user = user
        super(SelectForegin, self).__init__(attrs, choices)
```

And that's it, now my widget contains the current logged in user. It's not pretty imo, but it works.

**Note:**
This replaces all `ForeignKey` fields inside the `News` model. To fix this, there should be a custom `ForeignKey` sub-class used so that we can override that one only.

**If anyone has a better solution which is cleaner, please share and I'll accept.**